# How to mock a certain code using Rhino.Mocks?

Tags: .net, mocking, rhino-mocks

I have the following code:

```
public interface IFlowFolderHandler
{
  OperationResult Post(FlowFolder dto);
}

public class FlowFolderHandler : IFlowFolderHandler
{
  private readonly IResponse m_response;
  private readonly IEntityRepository m_entityRepository;

  public FlowFolderHandler(IResponse response, IEntityRepository entityRepository)
  {
    m_response = response;
    m_entityRepository = entityRepository;
  }

  public OperationResult Post(FlowFolder dto)
  {
    var ent = FlowFolderX.Cast(dto, true);
    m_entityRepository.Update(ent);
    var id = EntityIdComparer.IdToString(ent.Id);
    m_response.Headers["X-Entity-Id"] = id;
    return new OperationResult.Created
    {
      RedirectLocation = new Uri("FlowFolder/" + id, UriKind.Relative),
      ResponseResource = ent.GetEntityRelation(),
    };
  }
}
```

I wish to unit test the `FlowFolderHandler.Post` method, using `IResponse` and `IEntityRepository` mocks. My current implementation is using the following manual mocks:

```
private class EntityRepositoryMock : IEntityRepository
{
  private readonly Action<IEntityBase> m_update;
  public EntityRepositoryMock(int id, EntityRelation entityRelation)
  {
    m_update = ent => EntityRepository.ApplySaveSideEffects(ent, id, entityRelation);
  }
  public IEntityBase Fetch(EntityId entityId) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
  public void FetchByExpression(Type entityType, Expression expr, IList list, List<Pair<string, bool>> orderBy) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
  public void Update(IEntityBase entity) { m_update(entity); }
}

private class ResponseMock : IResponse
{
  public ResponseMock() { Headers = new HttpHeaderDictionary(); }
  public IHttpEntity Entity { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
  public HttpHeaderDictionary Headers { get; private set; }
  public void WriteHeaders() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
  public bool HeadersSent { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
  public int StatusCode
  {
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
  }
}
```

And the unit test is:

```
[Test]
[Factory("YieldPostFlowFolderData")]
public void PostFlowFolder(int id, Uri uri, EntityRelation entityRelation, FlowFolder flowFolder)
{
  var entityRepository = new EntityRepositoryMock(id, entityRelation);
  var response = new ResponseMock();
  var handler = new FlowFolderHandler(response, entityRepository);

  var result = handler.Post(flowFolder);

  Assert.AreEqual((int)HttpStatusCode.Created, result.StatusCode);
  Assert.AreEqual(id, int.Parse(response.Headers["X-Entity-Id"]));
  Assert.AreEqual(uri, result.RedirectLocation);
  SUC.Utils.AssertDeepEqual(entityRelation, result.ResponseResource);
}
```

My question is how can I write the same unit test (more or less) without the manual mocks `EntityRepositoryMock` and `ResponseMock` using Rhino.Mocks?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

My manual mocks contain a constructor only because they are manual mocks. I could have added a dedicated method `PrepareMock` instead of the constructor to make sure the mock is ready for ... mocking. Automatic mocks, the ones created by Rhino.Mocks, would not have any constructor related issues, because I would be mocking interfaces rather than concrete types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Mocks
var repositoryMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IEntityRepository>();
var responseMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IResponse>();
```

The using Expect() you can setup any expectation you want, for instance exp[ectation for the Update() method which is only one doing something rather than throwing exception:

```
repositoryMock.Expect(m => m.Update(null)).IgnoreArguments.WhenCalled(
   mi =>
   {
      IEntityBase passedInEntity = mi.Args[0] as IEntityBase;
      EntityRepository.ApplySaveSideEffects(passedInEntity, id, entityRelation); 
   }
).Repeat.Any();
```

Also one important point is mocking of the properties, you should specify `PropertyBehaviour()`:

```
repositoryMock.Expect(m => m.Entity).Proeprtybehaviour();
```

**EDIT:** To check that method was called once

```
repositoryMock.AssertWasCalled(m => m.Update(), mi => mi.Repeat.Once());
```

**Useful links:**

- See [Rhino Mocks - Arrange, Act, Assert Syntax](http://ayende.com/blog/3318/rhino-mocks-arrange-act-assert-syntax) for good examples and description

Comment: I am trying to implement your advice. First question - what is Repeat.Many() good for?

Comment: Next, I am trying to mock the response. `responseMock.Expect(m => m.Headers).PropertyBehavior();` does not work, because `Headers` is a read-only property. How can I tell the mock to return a certain object when the `Headers` propery is invoked?

Comment: Sorry, `Repeat.Any()`. It indicates that specified return value should be returned even method called multiple time, you can stric it to single method call by `Repeat.Once()` so each next call to mocked methiod will return null instead of return value (obviously for methods which return type is not void), this applies to `WhenCalled()`, it will be executed each time method is called not only first time

Comment: @mark: regarding property, to mock return value only use `responseMock.Expect(m => m.Headers).Return(Myproperty)` and in Myproperty you can throw exception. Myproperty - property defined in test class. To test exceptions you can use `Assert.Throws<NotImplementedExceptio>(() => responseMock.Headers)`

Comment: Excellent, it works. One more question, how can I make sure the `Update` method is called exactly once?

Comment: @mark : nice to hear, cheers! BTW - `repositoryMock.AssertWasCalled(m => m.Update(), mi => mi.Repeat.Once());`

Comment: how can I make sure the `Update` method is called exactly once?

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, are your "manual" mocks giving you troubles, or are you just looking for a cleaner way to implement them?  Sometimes the "manual" way is the best (simplest) way to go, as most mocking frameworks come with their own set of issues.

Anyway, having said that, the basic steps to mocking classes like you've done:

1. Create MockRepository object
2. Ask the MockRepository object to create a mock of your class/interface.  There are a lot of different kinds of mocks you can ask for (dynamic, partial, stubs, etc...), you will need to read the doc to figure out which one is appropriate for you.
3. Use the Do() handler to have your mocks execute specific bits of code that you want (it looks like this is what you are doing above, specifically with EntityRepositoryMock.Update

The Do() handler is documented here:
http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+The+Do()+Handler.ashx

Your mock objects also have code in the constructors.  FYI you might run into some issues with constructors.  From Ayende:

> A technical limitation with mocking classes is that the creation of a
>   mock object invokes the target class constructor, due to the mock
>   deriving from the target class.

This was from this page discussing ctors:
http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Mocking+classes.ashx

Comment: About constructors - I edited the post. On a general note, your response is a very polite form of RTFM, which is totally legitimate, but I'd rather have a ready to go example, from which I will figure the rest.

Comment: Didn't mean to come across as RTFM (although looking at my post I guess you're right).  I wasn't sure from your post if you had ever used Rhino.Mocks before, so I was just trying to give general direction with the Do() handler.  Looks like sll has a more concrete answer for you..